# Limit concurrent method invocation with Spring aop

Tags: spring, concurrency, aop

I want to limit concurrent method invocation in spring application.

There is [interceptor](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/1.2.x/api/org/springframework/aop/interceptor/ConcurrencyThrottleInterceptor.html) for this and [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Spring/ConcurrencyThrottleInterceptor.htm) the example of using this interceptor.
But the problem is that method(which need to be limited) is not in a bean, I am creating new object every time I need to call method. 
Is there is possibility to achieve limitation in this case?

Comment: Object synchronization policy is the innate part of the object design, while AOP is about addressing cross-cutting concerns, I'm sure there must be a more straightforward methods to implement this, for example designing a service that would take requests and process them in a queue. I.e. the synchronization information(which locks are  used and etc.) should not be put out of the class source file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Load-time weaving with AspectJ](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.3.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-aj-ltw) and write a custom `aspect` which does the throttling.

*Example*

```
@Aspect
public class ThrottlingAspect {
    private static final int MAX_CONCURRENT_INVOCATIONS = 20;
    private final Semaphore throttle = new Semaphore (MAX_CONCURRENT_INVOCATIONS, true);

    @Around("methodsToBeThrottled()")
    public Object profile(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {
        throttle.acquire ();
        try {
            return pjp.proceed ();
        }
        finally {
            throttle.release ();
        }
    }

    @Pointcut("execution(public * foo..*.*(..))")
    public void methodsToBeThrottled(){}
}
```